# libsvm grid.py on SGE cluster

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, sungridengine

As documented on libsvm website and readme file, the python tool **grid.py** can be run on different computers as mentioned here :

> "You can conduct a parallel grid search by dispatching jobs to a
>   cluster of computers which share the same file system. First, you add
>   machine names in grid.py:
>
> ssh_workers = ["linux1", "linux5", "linux5"]"

I have two questions here : Each of the commands that run through SSHWorker - are they independent of each other? It does not appear like they are trying to pass information between instances (e.g. MPI) - is that right?

My second question is: Can we modify this python script to run on SGE via qsub instead of providing nodes names inside the script ?

Thanks

Rad